# Having trouble aligning data using formattable in R

Tags: r, formattable

I put my data into a data frame and now want to align the data.

```
df.obs <- data.frame(Observer_Unanimous, row.names = TRUE)
```

[image: Basic formattable plot]

I now want to left align the first column (header), and center align the next three.

Code run:

```
formattable(df.obs, align = c("1", "c", "c", "c")) 

**Error in kable(mat, format = format, align = align, escape = FALSE, ...,  : 
  'align' must be a character vector of possible values 'l', 'r', and 'c'**
```

Not making progess!  Any thoughts?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this error stemmed from a typo in the code (1 vs l).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we directly apply `formattable` on the data.frame, it would work

```
library(formattable)
df1 <- head(iris)
formattable(df1, align = c("l", "c", "c", "c", "r"))
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you're open to using the `gt` package it's pretty straightforward. Here's a quick example using a subset of the `iris` data set:

```
df <- iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(Species, Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, Petal.Width) %>% 
  head()

df %>% 
  gt::gt() %>% 
  gt::cols_align(
    align = "center",  
    columns = 2:4
  )
```

[image: output]